# How can I echo it properly? HTML+PHP issue

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with this line,is there any solution for a line which must contain both single and double quotation marks?

```
echo "<a href='/ad/.$row['id_ad']'>".$row['title'];
```

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

Comment: try `echo "<a href='/ad/'".$row['id_ad']."'>".$row['title'];`

Comment: If you want to echo a value of an array key inside a string like that, you do _not_ quote the key (and you don't need the `.` concatenation operator. Inside the string, that's just a dot.). `echo "<a href='/ad/$row[id_ad]'>"` Outside a string, the key needs to be quoted, inside, not quoted.

Comment: Unless you're using complex syntax (curly braces) inside the string, then the key _does_ need to be quoted. `echo "<a href='/ad/{$row['id_ad']}'>"`. See [variable parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit the "echo" and concatenate with a dot.

```
echo "<a href='/ad/" . $row['id_ad'] . "'>" . $row['title'];
```

That would be the exact match of your line but I believe you forgot to close the anchor.

```
echo "<a href='/ad/" . $row['id_ad'] . "'>" . $row['title'] . "</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you kindly,it worked :)